# Given an array of numbers, the task is to print only those numbers which have only 1, 2 and 3 as their digits

Tags: java, arrays

Im currently working on a program to given integer input from user, print only those ones contain numbers 1 2 or 3. Here is my code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] x=new int[5];
    System.out.println("Enter 5 integers: ");
    for(int i=0; i<x.length;i++) {
        x[i]=s.nextInt();
        boolean temp=recursion(x[i]);
        if(temp==true) {
            System.out.print(x[i]);
        }
    }   
}

public static boolean recursion(int y) {
    if(y%10==1 || y%10==2 || y%10==3) {
        return true;
    }
    else if(y%10==0) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        int remain=y/10;
        recursion(remain);
    }

}
```

So my approach is quite simple, I used a simple bool recursion to return true or false, true if it does contain 1 2 or 3 and false if not. The problem I am having is that I am not returning anything in my recursion else statement. I know I have to return something but not sure what to return or if its necessary. Anything I can change to make this work?

Comment: Why not convert the number to a string and then check if each character is equal to "1", "2" or "3"?

Comment: Just return the recursion `return recursion(remain)`

Comment: Yea, I could also convert the numbers to string and check if ea char is 1 2 or 3. Im going to try that as well. That actually might sound easier. For some reason, the first thing that popped into my head was to approach it like this.

Comment: ...be carefull with the condition priorities (order), seems to me it returns true for 41...

Comment: I think for this task, 41 is supposed to return true, as '41' contains the digit '1'. I think its asking any integer that contains a single digit of 1 2 or 3 return true.

Comment: ok, you should know better, but in title you have "...have **only** 1, 2 and 3 as their digits..."

Comment: @Ryan Wilson If I do it by converting to string, is there a way to code it without a nested for loop? I just finished and my initial for loop takes in the values and puts into array, then within the for loop, i converted input to strings but i had to make another for loop to go thru each individual string to look for chars with 1 2 or 3.

Comment: @Java_Beginner There is a built in string function called Contains() which will search a string for you and return boolean whether it contains the passed in string, (https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-contains). I would recommend using that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your base cases for recursion are a little off, so in the statement
`else if(y%10==0)`, the number 100 would cause this to fail even though it is valid. you want your false base case to actually be `else if (y == 0)` which means you have gone through the entire number. the solution looks like:

```
public  static boolean recursion(int y) {
    int positive = Math.abs(y);
    if(positive%10==1 || positive%10==2 || positive%10==3) {
        return true;
    } else if (positive == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return recursion(positive / 10);
}
```

edit: Calling absolute value on the number makes it work for negative numbers as well, but you can call abs on the integer being passed in to the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just have to do

```
return recursion(remain);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use below code, hope this will help.**

```
public static boolean recursion(int y) {
    if(y%10==1 || y%10==2 || y%10==3) {
        return true;
    }
    else if(y%10==0) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        int remain=y/10;
        return recursion(remain);
    }

}
```

Comment: That function for 41 returns true... Oh, I see it's from original code...

Comment: Because we are calculating modulus.

Comment: Oh really? I though, that number should contain digits 1 or 2 or 3 only...

Comment: I am talking about first if condition.

Comment: Me, too. As I said, it returns true for 41, because of first condition 41 mod 10 is 1...